# Condition of being a measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I'm working on a measure theory problem and I'm completely stumped.

I'm trying to find out for *which integers $j$*, $\mu$ will be a *measure on $(\mathbb Z_+, \mathcal P(\mathbb Z_+))$* where $\mu$ is defined to be:
$$
\mu(E)=
\begin{cases}
 \sum_{n\in E}n^j&\text{if}\, c(E)< \infty\\
 \infty&\text{if}\, c(E) = \infty\\
\end{cases}
$$ 
*$c$ is the counting measure here.

I think I can simply consider finite sets or countable union of disjoint sets {${A_n}$}$_{n=1}^\infty$ where for some $N$, $A_n = \varnothing$ where $n\geq N$. Satisfying $\mu(\varnothing)$=$0$ is trivial, and since we are on $\mathbb Z_+$, $\mu(E) \geq 0$ for every $E \in \mathcal P(\mathbb Z_+)$. I think countable additivity would impose some condition on $j$, but not really sure of the point of attack here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **Hint:** For $j\le-1$ it's not $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: I don't really see how $j \leq -1$ implies that it's not countably additive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mu$ is defined as a sum over the elements, it is clearly finitely additive.

If $j\ge0$, then $n^j\ge 1$ for each positive integer $n$, so when we have infinitely many such numbers, they will sum up to infinity, matching the definition of $\mu$.

To see $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-additive for negative $j$'s, it's enough to consider only singletons. 
Specifically, the sum of the $\mu$ of singletons in $\{1,2,4,8,16,\dots\}$ is *finite* then.

Comment: Is the only issue the fact that {$1,2,4,8,16,...$} will have a finite measure if $j \leq -1$, which contradicts the construction of $\mu$? Is there anything else I should consider/worry about?

Comment: Yes, that's the only issue: if the measures of singletons are too low,  infinite of them might sum up only to a finite number, while $\mu$ measures every infinite set as infinite.